# Modify form field value when updating a different field in a ng-admin form

Tags: ng-admin

I need to update a 'datetime' field value in the EDIT view of an entity whenever I enabled a different checkbox field (put it to true).

**NGA fields**

```
nga.field('launchDate', 'datetime')
       .label('Launch date')

nga.field('active', 'boolean')
       .template('<active-game-field field="::field" entity="::entity" game="entry"></active-game-field>')
```

The thing is that, inside the directive I created for the 'active' template, I have to do some logic and from there I would like to modify the frontend element value of 'launchDate'.

Is there a way to easily do this, like for example with some attribute like '::fields', to pass all the fields of the form to the directive?

Right now I can get to the fields through require: '^form' or '::entity' but those values are only modify for the JSON request / response, and not the values on the frontend field.

**The directive**

```
module.exports = ['ngDialog', function activeGameField(ngDialog) {
return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'field': '&',
        'game': '&',
        'entity': '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {

        scope.updateLaunchDate = function (elem) {
            document.activeElement.blur();

            if (elem.value == true) {
                ngDialog.openConfirm({
                    template: '\
                    <p>Do you want to update the launch date of this game to now?</p>\
                    <div class="ngdialog-buttons">\
                        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click="confirm(false)">No</button>\
                        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click="confirm(true)">Yes</button>\
                    </div>',
                    showClose: false,
                    closeByDocument: false
                }).then(function (value) {
                    if (value) {
                        var date = new Date(Date.now());
                        scope.game().values.launchDate = date; // JSON value modified properly after clicking on save entity, but not the frontend value. In this callback I would like to do something like\'elem.value = date;' but for the 'launchDate' element instead if 'this' (active checkbox element).                   
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    template:
        '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" id="active" name="active" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" \
            ng-click="updateLaunchDate(this)">'
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like that much but at the end I solved this directly though JavaScrit accessing the 'launchDate' element by ID and modifying the element value.

```
document.getElementById("launchDate").value = dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
```

I would have liked it more doing it though angular or ng-admin but I could not figure out with this approach.